# What is starting all of these threads in my Spring application

Tags: multithreading, spring-boot, concurrency, quartz-scheduler, java.util.concurrent

I just started working on a legacy Spring Boot application, and I noticed it was not shutting down smoothly, required a hard kill to close it.

I did a thread dump and I see Spring is launching lots of threads that just don't want to die.

[image]

Ok, says I, must be the @Async's and @EnableAsync, we have a number of those to handle the initialization. I removed all of those, but no change.

Then I thought it might be Micrometer - we do a lot of instrumentation using @Timed, but I removed those and no change to the thread dump.

I searched for any instances of any kind of executor but nothing turns up.

What could be starting all of these threads and QuartzScheduler_Workers?